# Error when trying to join a channel via API

Tags: ios, swift3, slack, slack-api

im using slack to make chat bot so i can create a message center from my ios app to send message from ios app to slack.
getting following response from hitting joinChannel api https://slack.com/api/channels.join
cant get channel ids

```
{
  "provided" : "admin,identify,chat:write:bot",
  "ok" : false,
  "needed" : "channels:write",
  "error" : "missing_scope"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says you need the `channels.write` scope to use [`channels.join`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.join) method.

Just add the missing scope to your access token and it will work.